# How can I update the View from a Button in Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I created a discord bot for one game using discord.py library. One of the bot function is to display a message with buttons below. Once one of the buttons is pressed, the message is edited. The buttons can be red, green or gray depending on information, which is updated every day at given time. The point is, once I added "View" in bot, I cannot update it anymore to change the button colors as long the bot is working. My current solution is, that the docker container with the bot is reseted every day so at start it gets a new View.

I implemented my function with Buttons as follows:

```
class Buttons(discord.ui.View):
    bosses_always_expected = [...]
    bosses_world_changes = [...]
    bosses = []

    def __init__(self, bot, *, timeout=None):
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
        self.channel_logs = LOG_CHANNEL
        self.bot = bot


    @staticmethod
    def ifBossExpected(label):
        sorted_boss_list = tibia.expectations.readTableFromGuildStats(SERVER)
        for boss in sorted_boss_list:
            if label.lower().__contains__(boss.name.lower()):
           # if label in boss.name:
                print("match " + boss.name)
                return True

    @staticmethod
    def create_button(label, style):
        @discord.ui.button(label=label, style=style)
        async def button(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
            await self.handle_button_click(interaction, label)
        return button

    @staticmethod
    def replace_line(original_content, place, user, time, date):
        updated_lines = []
        for line in original_content.split("\n"):
            if place in line:
                text_checked = Buttons.create_txt(place, user, time, date)
                updated_lines.append(text_checked)
            else:
                updated_lines.append(line)
        updated_content = "\n".join(updated_lines)
        return updated_content

    @staticmethod
    def create_txt(place, user, time, date):
        return f"**{place}**: checked at {time} by {user} ({date})"

    async def handle_button_click(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, place: str):
        user = interaction.user
        current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
        current_day = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m")
        original_content = interaction.message.content
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(self.channel_logs)
        message = Buttons.create_txt(place, user.display_name, current_time, current_day)# user.mention was before
        await channel.send(message)

        new_content = Buttons.replace_line(original_content, place, user.mention, current_time, current_day)
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content=new_content)
```

I have more classes, which inherits after class Buttons and adding the buttons for specific post, for example:

```
class Venore(Buttons):
    bosses = ["Captain Jones", "Dharalion", "Rukor Zad", "Yaga The Crone", "Xenia"]
    def __init__(self, bot, *, timeout=None):
        super().__init__(bot, timeout=timeout)

    for boss in bosses:
        style = discord.ButtonStyle.red
        if Buttons.ifBossExpected(boss) or boss in Buttons.bosses_always_expected:
            style = discord.ButtonStyle.green
        if boss in Buttons.bosses_world_changes:
            style = discord.ButtonStyle.gray
        locals()[f"{boss.lower().replace(' ', '_')}_button"] = Buttons.create_button(boss, style)
```

in the main function is it implemented like below.
Once the bot is started, it loads the post in a specific channel with colorful buttons:

```
    await venore_checking(channel_thais_veno)
...
async def venore_checking(channel):
    venore = Venore(bot)
    message = "## Venore\n" \
              "**Captain Jones** has not yet been checked \n" \
              "**Dharalion** has not yet been checked \n" \
              "**Rukor Zad** has not yet been checked \n" \
              "**Yaga the Crone** has not yet been checked \n" \
              "**Xenia** has not yet been checked "
    await channel.send(message, view=venore)
```

Of some reason I am not able to create a separate function in Venore to create buttons (pack the code from "for boss in bosses:" in additional function because in this case the buttons are not displayed.
As you can see in the function venore_checking, at the end of the function view=venore is loaded. I haven't found a solution, where I can load the view on the fly while the bot is running (and therefore to change the colors of the button at given point of time).

Comment: For clarification, the class `Buttons` is not used directly and you are only using `Venore` which inherits from it, and the buttons are not showing, correct?

Comment: The class Buttons is not used directly.
If I implement it like this, the buttons from Venore are showing. When I add something like "create_buttons()" function and pack there "for boss in bosses:" and the stuff below (from class Venore) the Buttons are not showing anymore.

Comment: did you try it with "interaction.edit_original_response()" already?